# Calibre cannot load ImageMagick since upgrade to Vivid Vervet

Tags: shared-library, imagemagick, calibre

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 and now Calibre won't work.

```
File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/utils/magick/__init__.py", line 15, in
<module>   raise RuntimeError('Failed to load ImageMagick: '+_merr)*
RuntimeError: Failed to load ImageMagick: libIlmImf.so.6: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling Calibre and ImageMagick.

Here is the ImageMagick I have:

```
dpkg -l 'imagemagick*'

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  imagemagick    6.9.2-5      amd64        Use ImageMagick to convert, edit,
un  imagemagick-6. <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  imagemagick-6. 8:6.8.9.9-5u amd64        image manipulation programs -- qu
ii  imagemagick-co 8:6.8.9.9-5u all          image manipulation programs -- in
un  imagemagick-do <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Here is the Calibre I have:

```
dpkg -l 'calibre*'

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  calibre        2.33.0+dfsg- all          e-book converter and library mana
ii  calibre-bin    2.33.0+dfsg- amd64        e-book converter and library mana
```

I have some of my own Python code that invokes ImageMagick, and since the upgrade I get the same error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libIlmImf.so.6: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the Calibre package in the Ubuntu repositories, it is outdated and not very well maintained.

```
sudo apt-get remove calibre
```

Install Calibre with the command below, the author of Calibre provides a great installation script.

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py | sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"
```

This script lets you get version 2.41.0 without the problem of missing libraries.

[image]

More information [here](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux).